# How to avoid using a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause

Here a sample table :

```
A   |  B
----------
 DF   RUI
 EF   RUI
 AF   FRO
 EF   FRO
```

I want to get all results except WHERE (A = 'EF' AND B = 'RUI') like this :

```
  A   |  B
----------
 DF   RUI
 AF   FRO
 EF   FRO
```

But is it possible to do this without a subquery ?

EDIT :

I have add some extra results to show what I want to get. I want to get result if A = EF or B = RUI but i don't want to get result if A = EF AND B = RUI

Comment: Did you try to just use the code from your question?

Comment: The pseudo code ? No, in fact I want to know if it's possible to write this query without subqueries

Comment: So you just want the 2nd row excluded from the select results?

Comment: No I want get all results excepts results where A = 'EF' and B = 'RUI' but both conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a `NOT` condition in front of where clause:

```
SELECT A,B FROM table_name
WHERE NOT (A = 'EF' AND B = 'RUI')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A, B FROM table WHERE NOT (A = 'EF' AND B = 'RUI')
```

or

```
SELECT A, B FROM table WHERE (A <> 'EF' OR B <> 'RUI')
```

The where clause is essentially a boolean expression, so you can do any kind of boolean transforms that you're used to (it's a bit more complicated if it involved NULL values, which I assumed will not be the case for your example; if it does, you might need to add some additional rules or check the behaviour under [SQLs terinary logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29)).

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly . . .

```
select * from your_table
where not (A = 'EF' and B = 'RUI');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from SAMPLETABLE where A <> 'EF' OR B <> 'RUI';
```

Comment: DeMorgan's law.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, B FROM table WHERE (A = 'EF' XOR B = 'RUI')
```